# Making file input a not required field - bootstrap file input

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to make file input field not required , I have 2 fields for file input one is for profile picture and another for uploading documents.

If I do not select any image it says "You did not select file to upload" for both documents and profile picture

If I select a file it works perfectly fine.

The file field should not be mandatory.

I am using this plugin : http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo for front end design

Following is the code I tried on form submit

```
if(!array_filter($_FILES['docs']['name'])) {
            //upload file
        }



 if($_FILES['profile_pic']['name']!='') {
           //upload file
        }
```

What is wrong in the above code. Can anyone please tell why it is not working...

Comment: which parts of the code that output the "You did not select file to upload"? your php or frontend?

Comment: php code hence I wanted to put a condition before it reached the upload function but the condition does not seem to work..